# Reshaped second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, problem-solving

Does anyone know about some class of special functions starting with $(1+x^2)$ like this

$(1+x^2) y'' _{n,m} +f(x)y'_{n,m}+g(x)y_{n,m}=0$

where $f$ and $g$ are a function of $x$ and constants. I think it might be considered like a generalized Bessel.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or just a name of functions with this property?

Comment: The set of solutions is simply too diverse when we are allowed to choose $f$ and $g$ to say anything useful.

Comment: @Andrew Shedlock i am looking for just the special function with this structure

Comment: @ K.defaoite  i am looking for just the special function with this structure

Comment: @Medhi Even speaking about special functions, the possibilities for solutions $y$ to the above ODE are simply too broad to say anything, really.

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you please tell me the name of some special functions starting with $1+x^2$ ?

Comment: @Medhi Your question does not make sense. What do you mean starts with? I suppose $(1+x^2) {}_p F_q(x;[a_1,...,a_p];[b_1,...,b_q])$ would *technically* count, but of what use is this to you? $1+x^2$ is a polynomial - there is nothing "special" about it.

Comment: @ K.defaoite And what do you think about polynomials if we want to consider a second order differential equation with the first term $1+x^2$? Which types of polynomials can be listed in this case? Starting means the first term is $1+x^2$ since the famous polynomials start with $1-x^2$.